# Flutter: MouseRegion: onExit doesn't trigger when another window is overlapping the region and you exit the region via this window

Tags: flutter

like in the title.

I have a List with listTiles. Each tile is wrapped in a mouseRegion. I need this onExit event.

Update: OK: When reentering the app, an onExit event for the region where you left the app via the window is triggered. That is sufficient for me.